# If an array has an attribute, find the value of another attribute of the same array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

```
"dTableRowData": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "rowData": [
            "tt",
            "Sep13, 2010"
        ],
        "action": [
            {
                "hrefvar": "aaa",
                "label": "fff"
            },
            {
                "hrefvar": "bbb",
                "label": "Details"
            },
            {
                "hrefvar": "ccc",
                "label": "View"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Above is the array I have, and I need to find the value of "action" by taking the "id" (if action is present). Please help me achieve this using jQuery.

This question is closed

Comment: Your question is not clear. The value of `action` is an array. `id` seemingly has no bearing on the retrieval of `action`. If you attempt to retrieve `action` and it is not present in the object, you will receive `undefined`, which you can check for.

Comment: So, it should return the second element of the `action` array because `id` is `1`?

Comment: yea the value of "action" is an array, what i need is that action value by seeing the "id", so when parsing the array, take the "id" and print the "action" values. This is what i need

Comment: @wolle i need to achieve this by using jquery, i hope commonsense says it

Comment: First of all this is syntax error

Comment: how is that @maverick

Comment: it should be wrapped into something like `{` `}`

Comment: @Sweetz jQuery will do nothing for you here, javascript is what you need.

Comment: Actually, a clear question is what *we* need.

Comment: What is so hard with this? What did you already tried? Already tried using for-loops?

Comment: Please explain us, how to `find the value of "action" by taking the "id"`. Since the value of `action` is an array ob objects and the value of `id` is an string, this doesn't makes any sense.

Comment: Suggestion: give us a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6tRs/) showing code that you think should work and an example input and output of the function you're trying to write.

Comment: unclear question.. json tag required

Comment: Also, please don't mix PHP terminology with javascript. It confuses people who you want to help you answer this. The `id` attribute does not belong to any array at all. It belongs to an object. So the "attribute of the same array" phrase makes zero sense to people who work with javascript a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like bellow. You have a JSON like bellow.

```
var data = {"dTableRowData": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "rowData": [
            "tt",
            "Sep13, 2010"
        ],
        "action": [
            {
                "hrefvar": "aaa",
                "label": "fff"
            },
            {
                "hrefvar": "bbb",
                "label": "Details"
            },
            {
                "hrefvar": "ccc",
                "label": "View"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

You want to get an `action` for every object in `dTableRowData`. I added curly braces to `dTableRowData` other wise it will throw error.

So this is what worked for me using Javascript.

```
var actions = data.dTableRowData.map(function (obj) {
   // Get each object in data.dTableRowData and get action according to it's id from object
    return obj.action[obj.id];
});


console.log(actions);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it has got nothing to do with `jQuery`.
Second, its a syntax error.
You need to wrap this in `{` and `}` to make it valid.
You can use [this tool](http://jsonlint.com/) to check the validity of your JSON.

Next, this is how you do it. I've validated the JSON and added dummy data so that there is one element that doesn't have `action` attribute.

```
var array ={
    "dTableRowData": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "rowData": [
                "tt",
                "Sep13, 2010"
            ],
            "action": [
                {
                    "hrefvar": "aaa",
                    "label": "fff"
                },
                {
                    "hrefvar": "bbb",
                    "label": "Details"
                },
                {
                    "hrefvar": "ccc",
                    "label": "View"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "rowData": [
                "tt",
                "Sep13, 2010"
            ],
            "action": [
                {
                    "hrefvar": "aaa",
                    "label": "fff"
                },
                {
                    "hrefvar": "bbb",
                    "label": "Details"
                },
                {
                    "hrefvar": "ccc",
                    "label": "View"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "rowData": [
                "tt",
                "Sep13, 2010"
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

This is a function that returns all the IDs that have actions

```
function getRequiredIDs(myArray){
    var ids = [];

    for (var tableRowData in myArray.dTableRowData){
        var elements = myArray.dTableRowData[tableRowData];
        if(elements.action!=null){
            ids.push(elements.id);
        }
    }
    return ids;
}
```

And this is how you use it

```
var ids = getRequiredIDs(array);

var result = ""

for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
    result+=ids[i]+" ";
}

alert("IDs that have actions are - "+result);
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zSHN4/3/)

EDIT:

If you want to get `actions` for specific `id`, you need to change the code a bit like following.

```
function getRequiredActions(_id,myArray){
    for (var tableRowData in myArray.dTableRowData){
        var elements = myArray.dTableRowData[tableRowData];
        if(elements.id == _id){
            if(elements.action != null){
                return elements.action;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how you use it.

```
var actions = getRequiredActions("1",array);
console.log(actions);
```

[Final fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zSHN4/7/)